# Highest number in list and append

Tags: python, list, sorting, append

I am trying to find the largest number from the position 1 and position 2 in a list and return it to position 5 in the list. Tried this but is just says list index out of range. Any help appreciated.

```
for i in range( 0, len( sort ) ):
    if sort[i][2] > sort[i][1]:
        sort[i][2] = sort[i][1]
    sort[i][2].append
print(sort[i][5])
```

Comment: what you mean by *return it to position 5 in the list* ?

Comment: Could you paste the definition of `sort`?

Comment: Sorry. I mean store the highest score in position 5. I already have data in position 4 so appending it will also work. Thanks

Comment: is your indentation correct? if the last two lines are outside the for loop, then i == len(sort), so sort[i] will be out of range.

Comment: what exactly do you expect `highest_score = sort[i].append` to do?

Comment: also, examples of input and output would help understand what you are trying to do here

Comment: `sort[i][2].append` is just naming a method, not calling one, and there's clearly no `5` there anywhere, and according to your description `sort[i][2]` is a number rather than a list so it won't have an `append` method, so… why did you expect this to do anything useful?

Comment: I have amended the code - hopefully it now makes more sense. Find the biggest number from position 1 and 2, and then append this number to the next available position which is position 5. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code that have already been pointed out.

- append needs to be called with parentheses
- it needs to be called on sort[i] instead of sort[i][2]
- the print statement needs to be inside the for loop because once the for loop is done, i equals len(sort), so sort[i] will throw index out of range error

Consider this instead:

```
for i in range( len( sort ) ):
    sort[i].append(max(sort[i][1], sort[i][2]))
    print(sort[i][-1])
```

You can print sort[i][5] instead of sort[i][-1] if you are certain that that's the last index.

Comment: It doesn't? The question was to "Find the biggest number from position 1 and 2, and then append this number to the next available position". That is what my solution does.

Comment: You could probably improve the answer by adding this comment to the answer, to explain what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks. Really interesting how you have used the max function. I was going for the use of a convoluted bubble sort.